# Mui Datagrid columns panel make show all button disabled if all filters selected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

[image: datagrid columns panel]

In datagrid columns panel I want to disable show all button if all filters checked. I checked button classes for Mui-disabled to handle it from css but there is not. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 1):

to show is as disabled you can use  `opacity: 0.5,  cursor: "default"`

```
<DataGrid
       componentsProps={{
            columnsPanel: {
              sx: {
                "& .MuiDataGrid-panelFooter button:first-child":{
                   opacity: 0.5,
                   cursor: "default"
                }
                "& .MuiDataGrid-panelFooter button:last-child": {
                   opacity: 0.5,
                   cursor: "default"
                }
              }
            }
          }}
```

You can remove the buttons

```
 <DataGrid
   componentsProps={{
        columnsPanel: {
          sx: {
            "& .MuiDataGrid-panelFooter button:first-child": {
              display: "none" //removes the hide all button
            }
            "& .MuiDataGrid-panelFooter button:last-child": {
              display: "none" //removes the show all button
            }
          }
        }
      }}
```

so have a state to see if all columns are selected and conditional render the `sx` based on that.